# python email send to list one by one

Tags: python, email

I have a list of emails like this:

```
emails = ['a@a.a', 'b@b'b', 'c@c.c', 'd@d.d']
```

And this is my `for` loop:

```
for email in emails:
    message['To'] = email
    # ... other codes to send email
```

The problem is when I receive all three emails:

The first contact's `to` header is: `a@a.a`.

The second contact's `to` header is: `a@a.a` and `b@b.b`.

The third contact's `to` header is: `a@a.a` and `b@b.b` and `c@c.c`.

How can I send emails to all members without the mentioned problem?

I saw other answers but they still have issues.

I've been thinking about opening a file and having a list like this:

> In first iteration, the file should contain first email, then python reads the file and sends email to that. In second iteration the second email is written there and python sends email to only the second one, etc.

I tried to have a `with open` with mode `w` but only the last email is written in the file and that's another issue.

**Edit 1**

This is the full code:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import datetime
import pathlib

message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
sender_email = 'myEmail@gmail.com'
receiver_email = ['a@a.a', 'b@b.b', 'c@c.c']

password = 'myPass'
html = '<p>an HTML code</p>'

message['Subject'] = 'Some Subject'
message['From'] = sender_email
for receiver in receiver_email:
    message['To'] = receiver

    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    
    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)
    
    smtp = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login(sender_email, password)
    smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver, message.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

Comment: `# ... other codes to send email` I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in here...

Comment: @JohnGordon I edited question and added my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using the same `message` object over and over.

Each time you assign `message['To'] = receiver`, it's actually *adding* that address to the existing list of recipients.

To fix this, create a fresh new `message` object inside the loop.  Don't keep reusing the same one.

```
for receiver in receiver_email:
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['Subject'] = 'Some Subject'
    message['From'] = sender_email
    message['To'] = receiver
    ...
```